# Specflow+ tests don't appear in Resharper unit test explorer

Tags: automated-tests, resharper, specflow

I've installed Specflow+ and I'm using

```
<specFlow>
<unitTestProvider name="SpecRun" />
<plugins>
<add name="SpecRun" />
</plugins>
</specFlow>
```

But Resharper Unit Test Explorer doesn't show the tests. Any solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SpecFlow+ Runner has no support for the Resharper Unit Test Explorer. We currently support only the Visual Studio Test Explorer.

It is on our backlog to investigate how to bring the SpecFlow+ Runner into the Resharper Unit Test Explorer.

---

Full Disclosure: I am one of the developers of SpecFlow & SpecFlow+

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply!